# retrieve json from google app engine datastore

Tags: json, google-app-engine, datastore

I have stored some simple data in the GAE datastore.  Now I'd like to pull it out, but I'd like to do so with the results as JSON.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can first convert your datastore model to a dictionary and then use simplejson (python 2.5) or json (python 2.7) package to convert the dictionary to json.  Typically this is how the last line of your handler will look like:

```
self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(some_datastore_entity.to_dict()))
```

The new ndb interface to the datastore provides a to_dict method by default.  You can check it out [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict)

Comment: Not only the ndb interface has a to_dict: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#to_dict

Answer (score 1):

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        <do your GQLQuery here>
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.body = json.dumps(<your data in dict or dict list>)
        self.response.set_status(200)
```